# OpenLDAP ignores URI and host setting in ldap.conf

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to configure OpenLDAP client on SLED10 host and faced with some problems. I've specified URI field in config like `URI ldap://172.16.8.103:7323` but ldapsearch bails that it `Can't contact LDAP server`. With `ldapsearch -H ldap://172.168.8.103:7323` it works fine. Setting

```
host 172.16.8.103
port 7323
```

instead of URI returns the same error message. Moreover, `tcpdump` tells that no LDAP requests are performed at all in this case.  Other settings in config like BASE work fine. What can cause such problem and how to solve it?

Comment: To determine which ldap.conf file is being used, try executing `ldd $(which ldapsearch)`, then run strings on whichever libldap file is listed and grep for ldap.conf in the output of 'strings'.

Answer (score 2):

To know, what configuration file does ldapsearch consults, you may use one of this commands:

```
1) strings $(ldd $(readlink -e $(which ldapsearch)) | awk -F'(=>|[[:space:]]\\()' '$2 ~ /ldap/ {print $2}') | fgrep .conf
2) strace ldapsearch -x  2>&1 | fgrep .conf | grep -v '\(resolv\|nsswitch\|host\).conf'
```

In some unlikely cases you may need to install binutils package (by default it is installed on most distributives) or strace package first to run appropriate commands.

And yes you can use ".ldaprc" in your home directory and forget about searching of theoretically unpredictable system-wide path to ldap.conf at all.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that ldapsearch is using /etc/openldap/ldap.conf in my case and the first mentioned command showed this very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly ldapsearch isn't finding the ldap.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the version of openldap in SLES 10 supports this, but in SLES 11 you may specify the config file thru a env variable.

```
# LDAPCONF=/etc/ldap.conf ldapsearch
```